# Remove value from array in magento field

Tags: php, arrays, magento, array-difference

I have a magento custom collection and each item in the collection has its own landing page (collection/view/index/id/12 etc) in the frontend & managed in the admin backend.

I have a controller action that allows users to "**follow**" each item, with the users ID saved/added to the items field value.

*Example of the value of the Field/attribute below*

```
//Follow Action Working..
//Users ID added to field when followAction accessed via a follow link.

$model2 = Mage::getModel("userprofiles/userprofiles")->load($id);
$FollowProfiles = $model2->getFollowProfiles();
$model->setFollowProfiles(''.$FollowProfiles.''.$myprofileid.',');
$model->save();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Sucessfully followed.'); 
$this->_redirectReferer();

//saves as
123,321,220,125,
```

The follow action works as intended. However trying to get the unfollow action is not wanting to work. Code below.

```
//Get field/attribute values ie 123,234,345,456, 
$FollowProfilesArray = array($model2->getFollowProfiles());

//$profileid will be current users id
//used to remove user id from array
$remove_from_array = array_diff($FollowProfilesArray,array($profile_id,));

foreach($remove_from_array as $key => $value){
$select .= ''.$value.',';
}
//saves all ids except the removed users id
$model->setFollowProfiles($select);
```

Basically for some reason when using **array($model2->getFollowProfiles())** does not allow the removal of the user id from the field value saves it as 123,234,345,456,,

but..

when i set the array as a hardcoded value **array(123,234,345,456,)** it works and removes the id specified.

Any reason why **array($model2->getFollowProfiles())** does not work as it equals 123,234,345,456,

Do i have to implode, explode the **$model2->getFollowProfiles()** or something..??

Comment: codepad example with array data as a variable..seems array data as a variable doesnt work either..http://codepad.org/j24xuTSX

Comment: returns the same value output issue ie 123,234,345,456,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorted it out yeah. Code below.

---

*changed*

```
$FollowProfilesArray = array($model2->getFollowProfiles());
```

*to*

```
//explode out the attribute value
$FollowProfilesArray = explode(",","".$model2->getFollowProfiles()."");
```

---

*and changed*

```
foreach($remove_from_array as $key => $value){
$select .= ''.$value.',';}
```

*to*

```
    //so if $value is NULL save no value id, stoppped the adding of , to the attribute value

    foreach($remove_from_array as $key => $value){
    if($value == NULL) {
    //$select .= ''.$value.',';
    }else{
    $select .= ''.$value.',';           
    }
    }
```

---

so now on call to unfollowAction the specified ID is removed from the attribute value but keeps any other ID values.